# How does chrome establish the right character-encoding?

Tags: google-chrome, encoding, character-encoding, webkit, chromium

I've been working with a lot of charsets lately and I discovered a lot of issues when trying to establish the proper charset for a random web page. 
The charset can be set in the headers of the html document, or inside the `<head>` section, multiple times or sometimes the declaration is omitted. Despite these issues chrome dose a great job at setting the best charset every time.
I've tried searching [the sources](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/source/search) but didn't manage to find anything as I don't know where to look.
So my question is where could I find the algorithm?

Thanks

---

### update:

*problematic* example:

HTTP header of a document (based on server configurations):
    `Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8`
and the document looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>...</body>
</html>
```

Which encoding would be used to render the text?

Comment: You did not specify the sources. There seems to be a misunderstanding, as the character encoding cannot be changed within a document.

Comment: I'm not saying it changes, but it can be declared multiple times
`see update`

Comment: Either UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1 or CP1251 or Venusian. Really, it's Undefined Behavior. Typically, the HTTP header says it's a html text, yet you are sending a xml document (first error). Then, you don't say which version of HTML it is so it's supposed to be HTML4. In that case, the pragma should be used (http-equiv), but it's redefining the HTTP header, so it's unlikely to have effect at this time of parsing.

Comment: Often enough the answer is it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome uses https://github.com/google/compact_enc_det

If you want to read the actual code that calls that project, the function is [`DetectTextEncoding`](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/dea8b2608dd5d95e3869febc8b13d425291c19ef/third_party/blink/renderer/platform/text/text_encoding_detector.cc#L50) in the file `third_party/blink/renderer/platform/text/text_encoding_detector.cc`

Answer (score -1):

Headers charset will always overrule meta charset.

Comment: I've read but I don't think it is that simple,
I've learned that chrome is using it's language settings to guess the charset, and I think it has some sort of validation if for example a utf8 page is set to be ISO-8859-1 in both meta and html header and the page is rendered corectly in Chrome, probably detects BOM etc.