# Strip invalid utf8 from string in c/c++

Tags: c++, mysql, c, utf-8, mysql-connector

I have strings generated by **curl** from webpages like "[view-source:http://vvs24.com/component/contact/1.html](http://vvs24.com/component/contact/1.html)"
that have invalid utf-8 characters.

In my example 
`'advsearch': ' Avansert s�k'`, **�** = **ø** but in some other encoding than utf8.

How can I correct this error, as I need to insert the string into mysql (using the **C library**) and it gets trimmed at the invalid character, even after `mysql_real_escape()` as it's [documented](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?52,205660).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks as though the server has mislabeled some other encoding as UTF-8. So you have (at least) two options:

1) figure out what the real encoding is, and re-code from that to UTF-8. I think this particular page is Latin-1 (when I grab it with wget), but not all mislabeled pages necessarily are. For what it's worth, the most common mislabeling I see in practice is Windows CP-1252 advertised as Latin-1.

2) blindly strip out all characters with the top bit set (that is, with character values not in the range 0 ... 127), or replace with with a character such as `?`, on the assumption that the real encoding is some 8-bit code page or other, but you don't care what.

Comment: I've asked something like that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155467/how-does-chrome-establish-the-right-character-encoding/14382394#14382394) as to detecting the right charset. I've already went through those procedures but some pages have utf8 and some other characters pasted in so I go with what looks best.

Comment: So method 2 would be to do a `for(i=0;i<str.size();i++){if((int)str[i]>127 && (int)str[i]<0) str[i] = '?';}` ?

Comment: won't work
for example ø in utf8 has code (-61 , -72 ) so I strip these too and add 2 qustion marks

Answer (score 4):

Based on what [Steve Jessop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13005/steve-jessop) said I've ended up making a function that corrects most common errors and removes the rest.

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

string correct_non_utf_8(string *str)
{
    int i,f_size=str->size();
    unsigned char c,c2,c3,c4;
    string to;
    to.reserve(f_size);

    for(i=0 ; i<f_size ; i++){
        c=(unsigned char)(*str)[i];
        if(c<32){//control char
            if(c==9 || c==10 || c==13){//allow only \t \n \r
                to.append(1,c);
            }
            continue;
        }else if(c<127){//normal ASCII
            to.append(1,c);
            continue;
        }else if(c<160){//control char (nothing should be defined here either ASCI, ISO_8859-1 or UTF8, so skipping)
            if(c2==128){//fix microsoft mess, add euro
                to.append(1,226);
                to.append(1,130);
                to.append(1,172);
            }
            if(c2==133){//fix IBM mess, add NEL = \n\r
                to.append(1,10);
                to.append(1,13);
            }
            continue;
        }else if(c<192){//invalid for UTF8, converting ASCII
            to.append(1,(unsigned char)194);
            to.append(1,c);
            continue;
        }else if(c<194){//invalid for UTF8, converting ASCII
            to.append(1,(unsigned char)195);
            to.append(1,c-64);
            continue;
        }else if(c<224 && i+1<f_size){//possibly 2byte UTF8
            c2=(unsigned char)(*str)[i+1];
            if(c2>127 && c2<192){//valid 2byte UTF8
                if(c==194 && c2<160){//control char, skipping
                    ;
                }else{
                    to.append(1,c);
                    to.append(1,c2);
                }
                i++;
                continue;
            }
        }else if(c<240 && i+2<f_size){//possibly 3byte UTF8
            c2=(unsigned char)(*str)[i+1];
            c3=(unsigned char)(*str)[i+2];
            if(c2>127 && c2<192 && c3>127 && c3<192){//valid 3byte UTF8
                to.append(1,c);
                to.append(1,c2);
                to.append(1,c3);
                i+=2;
                continue;
            }
        }else if(c<245 && i+3<f_size){//possibly 4byte UTF8
            c2=(unsigned char)(*str)[i+1];
            c3=(unsigned char)(*str)[i+2];
            c4=(unsigned char)(*str)[i+3];
            if(c2>127 && c2<192 && c3>127 && c3<192 && c4>127 && c4<192){//valid 4byte UTF8
                to.append(1,c);
                to.append(1,c2);
                to.append(1,c3);
                to.append(1,c4);
                i+=3;
                continue;
            }
        }
        //invalid UTF8, converting ASCII (c>245 || string too short for multi-byte))
        to.append(1,(unsigned char)195);
        to.append(1,c-64);
    }
    return to;
}
```

references: [wikipedia](https://www.google.ro/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8&ei=7GETUvK3LKLV4gSP6oDYDQ&usg=AFQjCNEshz_Gx24Tb4MbTJgkT6C8lwYPcg&sig2=yzj-oPd0TDSDg3jlv3VdsA&bvm=bv.50952593,d.bGE), [utf8-chartable.de](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/)

## UPDATE 1

- added boundary check and improved a little bit
- still running some tests ( so use with caution )

Comment: It is necessary to check the string boundary when reading more than one character

Comment: @pogorskiy I guess you are referring to `(unsigned char)(*str)[i+1]`, and yeah you're right. I'll update. thanks